# Not a valid git branch name

Tags: git, git-branch

I am trying to create a new branch under feature tag of my repo, I am using following to do this:

```
 git branch "feature/BA-302-[AU]Intl-BCard"
```

However I am getting:

`fatal: 'feature/BA-302-[AU]Intl-BCard' is not a valid branch name`

Not sure, what I am missing. Also to clarify, I have already tried to:

```
git checkout -b feature/BA-302-[AU]Intl-BCard
```

With the following result:

```
zsh: no matches found: feature/BA-302-[AU]Intl-BCard
```

Comment: are you trying to create new branch ?

Comment: git checkout -b feature/BA-302-[AU]Intl-BCard

Comment: Yes I am trying to create a new branch with my current changes

Comment: Run command git checkout -b feature/BA-302-[AU]Intl-BCard  then git push -u origin feature/BA-302-[AU]Intl-BCard

Comment: Check my edit to the question

Comment: See `man git-check-ref-format` for valid ref names.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`[` is not allowed in a branch name. See [man-page for `git-check-ref-format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format) or [here](https://wincent.com/wiki/Legal_Git_branch_names) for more details.

In `zsh`, `[...]` defines a character class the shell tries to match. If there's no match, you get the error `zsh: no matches found`. Using quotes prevents the matching. In bash, similar behaviour can be turned on by running `shopt -s failglob`.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me - was scratching my head off! :D

Answer (score 17):

In my case it was a space. Branch name can't contain whitespace character.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced all spaces with underscores `_` and the branch created perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> Not sure, what I am missing

That is exactly what Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2953d95d402b6bff1a59c4712f4d46f1b9ea137f), addresses: when git refuses to create a branch because the proposed branch name is not a valid refname, an advice message is given to **refer the user to exact naming rules**.

See [commit 8fbd903](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8fbd903e58503cbdd1f1c816dd0c6c3c4d591b13), [commit 15cb037](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15cb03728f2fa6f153f873307ec92bb187681766), [commit 3ccc478](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ccc4782ce9b454c0428a7d6a4d0fd7c3d1eaea7), [commit 95c987e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95c987e6fad7cd3b3fe57542dbc6fb91532642d8), [commit 8c5001c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c5001c68e8f768e7b97cb5c366bc0b1e7a31ba7) (05 Mar 2024) by [Kristoffer Haugsbakk (`LemmingAvalanche`)](https://github.com/LemmingAvalanche).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b09a883](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b09a8839a4a09ab5bea79bcfe892b2591097319a), 15 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8fbd903e58503cbdd1f1c816dd0c6c3c4d591b13): advise about ref syntax rules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kristoffer Haugsbakk</sup>

> `git-branch(1)` will error out if you give it a bad ref name.
> But the user might not understand why or what part of the name is illegal.
>
> The user might know that there are some limitations based on the *loose ref* format (filenames), but there are also further rules for easier integration with shell-based tools, pathname expansion, and playing well with reference name expressions.
>
> The [man page for `git-check-ref-format(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format#_description) contains these rules.
> Let's advise about it since that is not a command that you just happen upon.
> Also make this advise configurable since you might not want to be reminded every time you make a little typo.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8fbd903e58503cbdd1f1c816dd0c6c3c4d591b13/Documentation/config/advice.txt#L97-L99):

> ### `refSyntax`
>
> Shown when the user provides an illegal ref name, to
> tell the user about the ref syntax documentation.