# Not a valid branch name

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I want to create a branch in git with name [WAP]Testing.
I tried

```
git checkout -b [WAP]Testing
```

I'm getting below error

```
fatal: '[WAP]Test' is not a valid branch name
```

Then I tried

```
git checkout -b '[WAP]Testing'
```

[as in mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612400/not-a-valid-git-branch-name).

But getting same error.

Comment: `[` and `]` are not allowed in a branch name. See `man git-check-ref-format` for more details: https://wincent.com/wiki/Legal_Git_branch_names

Comment: If they *were* allowed, you would certainly want to use quotes to avoid the possibility of your branch name expanding to one or more files named `WTesting`, `ATesting`, or `PTesting`.

Answer (score 4):

As it is mentioned [here](https://wincent.com/wiki/Legal_Git_branch_names) & [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format), you can't have `[` & `]` in a branch name.

Quoting:

```
5. They cannot have question-mark ?, asterisk *, or open bracket [ anywhere. 
See the --refspec-pattern option below for an exception to this rule.
```